# Java application slow on Windows and fast on Linux

Tags: java, performance, jframe, cpu-usage, graphics2d

I am developing this free and open source application that renders fractals. http://perceptron.sourceforge.net/

On my Windows, the application is 2 to 3 times slower than in Linux at this moment, probably because of a recent update of Ati Radeon driver (same version is used in Linux). The CPU frequency is not rising automatically when the application is executing (it stays at 1.4 GHz) unlike in Linux where it immediately rises to 3.4GHz.

(It runs fast using 64-bit Java and in Linux only at this moment. Using 32-bit version, it was never possible to obtain the fast execution for some reason. The performance issue due to 32/64-bit versions might be related with CPU frequency as well, given the same 1:3 ratio of slow/fast speeds under 32/64-bit versions. This points to the idea that the two versions utilize CPU at the lowest or higher frequency. Research details will be at the project page forum.)

I would like to know how to execute this JFrame application that continuously writes to the screen and secure fast operation across systems, for all future users, i.e. how to utilize CPU fully using Java.

Main class calls Perceptron in the following manner and the CPU priority has no effect at all on the speed.

```
    try {
        final Perceptron m = new Perceptron("resource/Settings.txt", "resource/CrashReport.txt", "resource/presets");
        Thread go = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                m.go(); 
            }
        };
        go.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        go.start(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: why can't you use 64 bit java on windows, same as linux? without it and other hardware parameters you arn't making a fair comparison.

Comment: I am using 64-bit version on both systems in fair conditions. I was looking for an answer, apart from the current topic, why 64-bit version is fast and 32-bit version is slow, firstly because I didn't know how NetBeans ran it fast and otherwise execution were slow. It was about 3 years ago. Then I searched for an answer for other users who have no 64-bit version installed. I also had problems on my old computer with automatic java updates (which for example, defaults to 32-bit version) and driver updates, trouble with preferred Java version on different machines and so on and on.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished very good speed in Windows by setting advanced CPU options in my Asus motherboard BIOS, CPU Core Leveling = One Compute Unit Per Core. This option is pertinent to AMD A10 APU (CPU with built-in GPU). The performance is excellent and the frequency scales back down quickly if I open another application and work in it.

It would be necessary however, to know how to manipulate CPU/GPU programmatically, i.e. to write a code  in Java or a C code for the "starter" application that keeps the CPU utilization going, because it would help other users who encounter similar situation. Also, few days ago I used Ultra Fractal to "heat up" the CPU and my application worked fast simultaneously, so a "starter" application could do it, although it seems like a workaround around around.

My newly found solution is a bit imperfect. The frequency periodically oscillates, goes up and down a little bit every maybe 20 seconds. Also, computer performance is peculiar! Lets see a comparison...

3dmark
Version: 1.1
SystemInfo Version: 4.22.0.0
November 30 2013

Configuration

AMD A10-5700
AMD Radeon HD 7660D
ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. F2A85-M LE
64-bit Windows 8 (6.2.9200)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Automatic core leveling

ICE STORM

3DMark Score
42261.0 3DMarks
Graphics Score
46575.0
Physics Score
31916.0
Graphics Test 1
180.9 fps
Graphics Test 2
229.9 fps
Physics Test
101.3 fps

CLOUD GATE

3DMark Score
5595.0 3DMarks
Graphics Score
7987.0
Physics Score
2732.0
Graphics Test 1
34.2 fps
Graphics Test 2
35.2 fps
Physics Test
8.67 fps

FIRE STRIKE

3DMark Score
1049.0 3DMarks
Graphics Score
1159.0
Physics Score
3734.0
Combined Score
377.0
Graphics Test 1
5.44 fps
Graphics Test 2
4.7 fps
Physics Test
11.9 fps
Combined Test
1.76 fps

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

One compute unit per core... or is it one core per compute unit....? nevermind.

ICE STORM

3DMark Score
43003.0 3DMarks
Graphics Score
67942.0
Physics Score
18822.0
Graphics Test 1
294.8 fps
Graphics Test 2
296.0 fps
Physics Test
59.8 fps

CLOUD GATE

3DMark Score
4406.0 3DMarks
Graphics Score
8052.0
Physics Score
1705.0
Graphics Test 1
33.8 fps
Graphics Test 2
36.3 fps
Physics Test
5.42 fps

FIRE STRIKE

3DMark Score
1042.0 3DMarks
Graphics Score
1168.0
Physics Score
2356.0
Combined Score
395.0
Graphics Test 1
5.42 fps
Graphics Test 2
4.78 fps
Physics Test
7.48 fps
Combined Test
1.84 fps

Answer (score 0):

With default settings in BIOS, the problem of slow execution under Windows comes down to the CPU power management in Windows. Java application does not make the CPU switch to higher frequency. In the center of this behavior is the current Catalyst manager of Ati Radeon graphics card. In Catalyst, it is possible to fixate the frequency at the highest frequency, which solves the problem, but is not the default setting. Also, in Control Panel, in Power Plan, advanced settings also contain the lowest and the highest CPU frequencies. These are by default set to widest range, but setting them to only the highest value solves the problem for Java. This setting seems unnatural to me though. A favorable solution would be to control the CPU governor from within the program as needed, if it already does not react to the demands of the system by itself. However, it does react to many C/C++ programs and standard tests by itself.

Answer (score 0):

After months of waiting, the latest version of Ati Radeon DRIVER FOR WINDOWS, allows the CPU to raise the frequency to maximum after loading my Java application. This is a factor of about 3 times the lowest frequency, which speeds up the application. The reason why Ati Radeon driver affects CPU is perhaps because I have a combined CPU/GPU unit, AMD A10 5700, so the unit is controlled as either CPU or GPU. Asus AI Suite II has been set to EPU: high performance mode, while the windows power options are mostly at default values. As you can see, there are 3 places that try to configure the same thing, i.e. power options. Ati Radeon driver controls these options through its own presets and these affect the CPU frequency both baseline and upscaling. All possible combinations of options in the previous months have failed in Windows. Linux however, was not affected by these issues.

These notions caused widespread disbelief, so I am adding some photos to show the options I am talking about...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here you can see how it scales up when my Java application is running with the new Ati driver.

[image]

However, the road to this solution was not straightforward. After installing new driver, nothing new happened. I selected the Gaming preset in Radeon control center and got a fixed value of frequency set at its highest possible point at all times. I knew that Ati made a new feature, but I wanted the frequency scaling to work, so I re-selected the default power options in Asus AI Suite II and in Windows control panel, and so the result emerged.